# JSON Document Fields in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm sorry I just don't plain get iteration through JSON.  I need help please.  I am doing simple shell module commands to get processor, memory, and disk space.

I create a set_fact: and add that information in.  This is what the running playbook spits out.  It is a fact called **payload_list**.

```
 "ansible_facts": {
    "payload_list": [
        {
            "name": "Hostname", 
            "output": "test_server", 
            "rc": "0", 
            "threshold": "0"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Uname", 
            "output": "Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64", 
            "rc": "0", 
            "threshold": "0"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Uptime", 
            "output": "22:09:17 up 91 days  3:44", 
            "rc": "0", 
            "threshold": "0"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "CPU", 
            "output": "99.05", 
            "rc": "0", 
            "threshold": "1"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Memory", 
            "output": "4GB", 
            "rc": "0", 
            "threshold": "1"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Disk Usage", 
            "output": "40", 
            "rc": "0", 
            "threshold": "1"
        }
    ]
}, 
"changed": false, 
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "payload_list": [
            {
                "name": "Hostname", 
                "output": "test_server", 
                "rc": "0", 
                "threshold": "0"
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Uname", 
                "output": "Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64", 
                "rc": "0", 
                "threshold": "0"
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Uptime", 
                "output": "22:09:17 up 91 days  3:44", 
                "rc": "0", 
                "threshold": "0"
            }, 
            {
                "name": "CPU", 
                "output": "99.05", 
                "rc": "0", 
                "threshold": "1"
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Memory", 
                "output": "", 
                "rc": "0", 
                "threshold": "1"
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Disk Usage", 
                "output": "", 
                "rc": "0", 
                "threshold": "1"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "module_name": "set_fact"
}
```

}

How to I pull out a single **key:value** or even a **value**.
I cannot use json_query because it expects something to be installed so that is not an option for me.  Using Ansible version 2.2.1.

Thanks in advance for clearing this up so I can learn.

Comment: Please specify your objective. You already pulled the values all at once, but that doesn't satisfy you. No one but you knows what you want.

Comment: I have the values but how do I select individual values of a specific key.  So for the CPU.output I want to have a statement or evaluation of that value.  So it is an idle number that Cpu.output.  I want to know how I would call it out or single the value out to see if it is less than say 95.00

Comment: "*to see*" - you can use your eyes. However, if you wanted to use the value in some code, please publish that code.

Comment: If this is what you want, it's a duplicate of [yesterday's question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43902117/2947502).

Comment: Something to this effect.  Printing Name and Output to File

That code is not entirely functional but something similar to this:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bfe7ed5ed1109cf5a524beeefdf5fca5

Answer (score 0):

To fetch individual objects from a list, you can use `selectattr`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    payload_list: [ { "name": "CPU",    "output": "99.05", "rc": "0", "threshold": "1" },
                    { "name": "Memory", "output": "4GB",   "rc": "0", "threshold": "1" } ]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{item}} = {{ (payload_list | selectattr('name','equalto',item) | first).output }}"
      with_items:
        - CPU
        - Memory
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help I'll be working on this shortly.  I'll let you know what happens with it.

Comment: When I attempt a run on that book as is above I get some errors so I'll try and work through it but it does look like at least on Ansible 2.2.1.0 I am getting issues.  Errors are too numerous to post here so I placed them here.  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0edb94fc23f7d09652c592396324fd2b
HOWEVER: Testing it LOCAL on my Development Station it works fine so there is an issue with the Ansible setup on the server.  That I may not have the authority to get around.  Are they any other ways that you are aware of to single out the data without selectattr?  In not that's fine.

Comment: The below works. https://bpaste.net/show/7d2e7ac72ab2
`---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    payload_list: [ { "name": "CPU",    "output": "99.05", "rc": "0", "threshold": "1" },
                    { "name": "Memory", "output": "4GB",   "rc": "0", "threshold": "1" } ]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Name: {{ item.name }}, Value: {{ item.output }}."
      with_items: "{{ payload_list }}"
      when: item.name == 'Memory'
`